# Drop indexes of all tables in current selected database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, nested-loops

I am trying to drop all indexes which are generated as the result of foreign key, for which I wrote a stored procedure, but MySQL server complains about syntax, procedure is this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_DropIndexOfTables;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DropIndexOfTables()
BLOCK1: BEGIN
 DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE v_table varchar(200) DEFAULT "";
  DEClARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR

         SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA=(SELECT DATABASE());

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN table_cursor; 
    LOOP1: loop
           FETCH table_cursor INTO v_table;
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
             CLOSE table_cursor;
         leave LOOP1;
            END IF;

        BLOCK2: BEGIN
              DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
              DECLARE v_index varchar(200) DEFAULT "";
              DEClARE index_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT INDEX_NAME   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())   AND INDEX_NAME in ( SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME  FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS  
                    WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())   AND TABLE_NAME = v_table);
                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
        OPEN index_cursor; 
        LOOP2: loop
        FETCH index_cursor INTO v_index;
        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        close index_cursor;
            leave LOOP2;
        END IF;
        SET @v_query = CONCAT('DROP INDEX ',v_index,' ON ', v_table);
                PREPARE stmt FROM @v_query;
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                END loop LOOP2
              END BLOCK2;
  END loop LOOP1;
END BLOCK1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL usp_DropIndexOfTables()
```

I am unable to figureout what I am doing wrong!

**Error**

```
mysql> source dropIndexs.sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END BLOCK2;
  END loop LOOP1;
END BLOCK1;

END' at line 39
ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE dbname.usp_DropIndexOfTables does not exist
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you run procedure???

Comment: @BK435  added the error in question.

Comment: 'END loop LOOP2' does not have a semi-colon after it.  Have you tried placing one after it and rerunning create procedure?

Comment: Nice catch, Thanks but it now says `mysql> source dropIndexs.sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)
`

Comment: If I would guess, since that error does not tell me much except for its an issue with the "end" at line 1, but there is no end there...I would take a look at your `End$$ Delimiter;` lines...I think something is awry there...Double check syntax on that and make sure you are ending what you think you are ending...